Missed the implementation didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler
I embedded the SFMC SDK with the SDK for native use in my Flutter apps before the Flutter version of the SFMC SDK was released.
I recently updated to Xcode16 and iOS18 respectively when they were released.
At that time, I started getting runtime errors, so I updated Podfile.lock to the following
PODS:
  - MarketingCloud-Cdp (2.0.4):
    - MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk (~> 1.1.0)
  - MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk (1.1.3)
  - MarketingCloudSDK (8.1.3):
    - MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk (~> 1.1.3)

After updating Podfile.lock, the runtime error disappeared, but the following error appeared.
❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌

 SFMC SDK is not configured correctly. 

❌ Issue: Missed the implementation of following function:

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

Result: Push features will not work correctly.

✅ Suggestion: Implement the following function in AppDelegate:

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    SFMCSdk.requestPushSdk { mp in
      mp.setNotificationUserInfo(userInfo)
    }
    completionHandler(.newData)
  }


Helpful Docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/mobile-push-sdk.html

❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌

Other methods defined in the same class and listed in the documentation (didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, didFailTorRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError) do not generate any No errors.
Why do I get an error that only the didReceiveRemoteNotification method is not implemented?
I can't paste the full text, but here is the implementation.
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate{

    // omission...

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        // omission...
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    override func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        // omission...
    }

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                              continue continueUserActivity: NSUserActivity,
                              restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        // omission...
    }

    // MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        SFMCSdk.mp.setDeviceToken(deviceToken)
    }

    // MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {}

    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // omission...
    }

    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        // omission...
    }

    // MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        SFMCSdk.mp.setNotificationUserInfo(userInfo)
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}


I have the same problem  Look like it's working in simulator but not in real device
